# Visual studio 2010 ODAC Oracle ORA-12154

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, tnsnames

I can connect to remote Oracle db using Oracle SQL Developer after tuning TNSNAMES.ora. I can also connect to remote Oracle db using export import vizard in SQL server. 
When do tnsping sourcename on command prompt, I get the correct response. This shows my TNSNAMES is correct.

But when I try to add datasource in Visual Studio 2010 under server explorer, it gives me ORA-12154!!

Based on a couple of suggestions in forums, I added the below line to sqlnet.ora

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP, TNSNAMES, HOSTNAME)
```

but I still get the same error!

The Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 11.2.0.3 is installed.

Comment: This is filed as Bug 3807408 at oracle support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your TNS. Check these three solutions :

Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)

Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper directory and is accessible.

Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.